# Detecting patterns from a collection of data

Tags: python

I have a collection of data for a multiplayer game (2000 games, 10 players each). I would like to create clusters from this data, each containing the ids of 3 players that had played against each other.

Comment: Just to verify: If A played against B, C, and D, and B and C each played against D, too, do you want to recognize clusters {A,B,D} and {A,C,D}?

Comment: Eventually you may want to build a complete digraph of all games ad use topological sort to extract same-level teams.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to SO and stats: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/272808/7828

Comment: You are looking for cliques, not for clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python `networkx` module to find all 3-cliques:

```
import networks
G = nx.Graph() # The clique locator does not work with digraphs
G.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('A','D'),('A','C'),('B','D'),('C','D'),('D','E')])
[clique for clique in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G) if len(clique)==3]    
#[['B', 'A', 'D'], ['A', 'D', 'C']]
```

Finding all clique may take a lot of time and memory. Luckily, `nx.enumerate_all_cliques` is a generator that produces smaller cliques first, so you can stop retrieving cliques after you get a clique with more than 3 nodes:

```
cliques=[]
for c in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G):
  if len(c) < 3: continue
  if len(c) > 3: break
  cliques.append(c)
print(cliques)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this did not work for me. Maybe it's because it's the first time i hear of this module. I read the api but its implementation did not work. Anyhow, i am trying to solve this problem using a clustering technique such as dbscan since all i want to do at this stage is just group the ids of players A,B, and C.

Comment: Why do you care about the implementation, when you can simply call the functions?